# x86_64 Dot Vector Product Intrinsic to ARM64

Tags: assembly, vectorization, sse, arm64

I am porting a small C routine that includes x86_64 intrinsics to a ARM64 platform. I am unable to find an equivalent ARM64 intrinsic for _mm_dp_pd.

I do have access to the arm neon intrinsics.

I am not sure how to replace x86_64 intrinsic with a ARM64 equivalent.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#ifdef ARM64
    float32x4_t a, b;
#else
    __m128d a, b;
#endif

#ifdef ARM64
    ????
#else
    res = _mm_dp_pd(a, b, mask);
#endif
```

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: "I assume float32x4_t a; can replace __m128d a;" bad start.

Answer (score 1):

[`dppd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/DPPD.html) isn't faster than a vertical multiply / shuffle / add, and in fact decodes to 3 uops on Intel CPUs (https://agner.org/optimize/) which probably do exactly that (with maybe some extra bonus stuff for the mask).

e.g. on Skylake, it's 9c latency with 2 uops for p01 (where the FMA units are) and 1 uop for p5 (where the shuffle unit is).

It's even slower on AMD before Ryzen (e.g. 7 uops on Steamroller), but Ryzen decodes it as 3 uops.  (`dpps` is still slow, though, in case you actually want four 32-bit `float` elements (`float32x4_t`) instead of two 64-bit `double` elements (`__m128d`)).

---

Anyway, assuming you want the dot-product result broadcast to both elements of a `double` vector, do a vertical multiply, then swap one vector and do a vertical add.

Porting this to ARM should be easy

```
__m128d prods = _mm_mul_pd(a,b);
__m128d swap  = _mm_shuffle_pd(prods,prods, 0b01);
__m128d dot   = _mm_add_pd(prods, swap);
```

Or if you only care about the low element, then you can use a simpler shuffle like `movhlps` ([Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86/35270026#35270026)).

If you need the upper element zeroed, like `dppd` can do, then it might take an extra instruction on AArch64.

---

And BTW, if you're doing a lot of DPPD, you might want to look at changing your data layout to a struct-of-arrays, so you can do two dot-products in parallel without any shuffling, with a mul and an FMA.  See https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/ for a good explanation of designing your data layout / whole approach to be SIMD friendly

But horizontal stuff outside an inner loop isn't always bad.